# div container sizing issues

Tags: css, html, size

Earlier I asked a question about horizontal positioning of div containers, now I've got follow up and related questions:

(1) As you can see in the HTML code below, I've got a "column_bottom" container (for links) placed to the left of a "content_bottom" container (for the page's main content).
As I type more content into the "content_bottom" container so that its height exceeds that of the left "column_bottom" container, the entire "content_bottom" container shifts to BELOW the "column_bottom" container. What can I do so that the left "column_bottom" container's height dynamically match the height of the right "content_bottom" container (and they stay horizontally next to each other)?

(2) As you can see in the CSS style sheet below, I tried to manually set the widths of the "column_top" and "column_bottom" to match in em units by trial and error. Would there be any issues with this method across different browsers on different systems? What can I do to ensure that "column_top" and "column_bottom" widths always match?

Thanks for your help.

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>this is the site's title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="penonek.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="column_top">site<br>
</div>
<div class="content_top">&nbsp;title<br>
</div>
<div class="column_bottom">
<ul>
<li>home</li>
<li><a href="#">link 1<br>
</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link 2<br>
</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link 3<br>
</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="content_bottom">main content here<br>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #cccccc;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 60em;
  max-width: 60em;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  width: 60em;
  color: #cccccc;
}
.column_top {
  border-width: 0 0 0.25em;
  border-bottom: 0.25em solid black;
  width: 3.2em;
  min-width: 3.2em;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 2em;
  text-align: right;
  color: #333333;
  max-height: 1em;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  font-size: 3em;
  min-height: 1em;
  max-width: 3.2em;
  height: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
}
.content_top {
  border-width: 0 0 0.25em;
  border-bottom: 0.25em solid #f4f4f4;
  padding-top: 2em;
  font-size: 3em;
  min-height: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  max-height: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
}
.column_bottom {
  width: 9.28em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 3em;
  color: #333333;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-right-width: 0;
  padding-right: 0.3em;
  float: left;
  border-left-width: 0;
  min-width: 9.28em;
  max-width: 9.28em;
}
.content_bottom {
  padding: 3em 5em 5em;
  border-collapse: separate;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
.column_bottom ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333333;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: inherit;
}
.column_bottom a:hover {
  background-color: #999999;
}
.column_bottom a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: inherit;
  color: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a wrapper for .content_bottom with this css:

```
.content_bottom_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -9.58em;
    float: right;
}
```

And add this to content-bottom:

```
margin-left: 9.58em;
```

9.58em = width of .column_bottom + padding-right on .column_bottom

http://jsfiddle.net/p93fM/

Comment: Ah that works! But is there a way so that if the .content_bottom container's contents gets really long, the left .column_bottom container will dynamically adjust its height to keep up???

Comment: There is no way to set the height, but there is a way to make it seem like that. See http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/ for explanation, example.

Comment: Why do I need to use 9.58em for the bottom column, but 3.2em for the top column? Can I be sure their widths will be the same?

Comment: I didn't want to change anything in your css, I just added a couple of lines. If you want to make sure the bottom and top columns have the same width, you can set the same width to them. Just make sure you update the margin-left attributes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/PpL52/1/)

I added this to `.content_bottom` in CSS

```
width:640px;
```

You can adjust the margins as you wish.

Comment: You are using that .column_bottom's height is currently ~6em, so if he adds more links to the ul he will have to adjust the css.